# Is it possible to buy the Cargobob?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-online

Is it currently possible to **buy** the Cargobob in GTA Online on the PC?

I read on some sites that it is possible through the phone (through changing the URL in the web browser), but has this been patched by Rockstar yet?

Are other Methods where i could buy the Cargobob?

PS: I know that it spawns randomly on some airfields but i want to buy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very old glitch which was patched a long time ago.

They spawn at helipads but you can get shot by the homing launcher pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Currently,no.I believe if you call lester and ask him to find you a helicopter,it is either always or sometimes the cargobob.It might be added in the future though.

Answer (score -1):

It is available on the PC, in Storymode, but not in online.

Comment: Information on how to obtain it is counter-produtive, as it is simply not available in online, which is what OP is asking for in the first place.